# Touchpad stops working (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, configuration, touchpad, asus

I'm on Arch Linux and using i3 as DE. I have an Elantech touchpad, shown on the list below. My computer is the Asus E403SA-WX0004T.

The touchpad just stops working. Suddenly, at any given time, it may be disabled and can't be used anymore until the next reboot (if I plug in a mouse, this one works fine, but does not re-enable the touchpad whatsoever). Its entry in `xinput` is still unchanged though, still recognized, but disabled for some reason.

Output of `$ xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Content of the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event4"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

(Its event number changed from 5 to 4 since the last time I checked. If I may ask another question, is there any way to always keep the right number? I have no clue if it can be the solution to this problem.)

Don't hesitate to ask for whatever is missing, I'll gladly add whatever you feel necessary.

Comment: It appears that if I plug the mouse before I start the computer (OR before doing anything, maybe before launching startx? Xorg related? I didn't check while plugging it between powering on the PC and 'startx'), my touchpad does not stop working at all during a whole day, 8 hours straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has disappeared since long ago now, I assume it has been corrected in a previous kernel version.